# Get previous data on realtime updates with Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to get previous data on realtime updates with firestore?

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
        if (change.type === "added") {
            console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
            //I need previous data here
            console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "removed") {
            console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`snapshot.docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) always contains the entire set of documents that are currently matched by a query, so it will contain every document added and modified.  But if a document is deleted from the query, it will no longer be there.  You will have to make a record of those on your own.  The SDK will not do that for you.